# How can I BBQ everyday without the cleaning?

Tags: barbecue

I want to BBQ everyday with a small BBQ but I do not want to wait to have to light coals, and then wait on the grill and then clean.

Is there an easier way to BBQ frequently?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question after some editing. Some old timers would say BBQ'ing isn't something you can rush - that's what grilling is for ;P

Comment: Besides "disposable barbecues" (or "camping barbecues" as we call them here) I don't see how this is possible. I think your options are either to make enough money to have someone clean it after every use, or get someone to make a TV series about you BBQ-ing everyday, and make the producer pay for the clean up. There tends to be quite a gap between TV series and reality, sorry.

Comment: Ouch - not sure on all the downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a gas grill will get one ready to cook faster than using charcoal. Using gas also cuts down on cleaning out ashes.

If grilling everyday I would clean the next day when the grill was hot, right before I started cooking. And cleaning would be a quick scrub with a grill brush. A periodic more through cleaning might be needed.

Comment: If it's a natural gas BBQ you also eliminate the trips for propane (and propane accessories).

Comment: **DON'T** use a grill brush. It will bring you to the hospital! https://www.thespruceeats.com/quality-grill-brushes-333585 Better: heat up the grill, then take tin foil to scrub it.

Comment: Not really an answer. You're basically saying 'do something else'  rather than answer the question.

Comment: Is grilling with natural gas systems the same as a George foreman?

Comment: No, @TheBlackBenzKid . George Foreman is simply one brand of grills/bbqs. Generally, grilling can be produced by burning coal, burning gas, or electrical. Gas has the advantage to not have coals or ashes, and get burning on full roar in one second (but you can't buy it in bags).

Comment: Sorry @Aganju your last point that you can't buy in bags meaning?

Comment: I just meant that buying/storing gas is more complex than buying coal

Answer (score 0):

Some friends bought a gas barbecue and line with tin foil to save on cleaning.